# Linux security(?) issue Ctrl+Alt+F7/F8

Tags: security, users

Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS amd64.

User A logs into Ubuntu. Then he switches to user B. Now user B can access user A's GUI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

User A can also access user B's GUI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

There is no difference whether users are sudo users or not. No passwords or any other type of authentication is required.

How to prevent such behavior?

(I'd prefer not to disabling this feature/key combination, just to harden it.)

Comment: how about account locking before leaving workplace by user A, or user B? So switching will not be insecure)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't lock accounts since they've been used in a network (one user/multiple seats).

Comment: @vtw3 Are you sure that locking the desktop will lock all of their sessions? It seem like locking from the dropdown menu would just lock the current gdm session on that desktop but I could be wrong.

Comment: According to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1806961) they installed `light-locker` to lock the screens between sessions. Also, this is what I am using with lightdm (although you are probably using gdm, it might still work). I can switch users from userA to userB and when I CTRL+ALT+F7 I get a lock screen. However, when I switch back to F8 I don't get a lock screen because the userB session has not been previously locked.

Comment: "prevent such behavior" by reporting the bug.